# Real time dominant color detection on iOS camera input

Tags: ios, image, swift, colors, camera

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that detects the dominant color in real time of the iPhone's camera.

I Already tried to implement some of the algorithms I found, but had loss of performance.

I would like some advice and direction for research.

If I can't find anything I will have to try a parallel implementation with Accelerate, SIMD, Metal, or dispatches.

Any recommendations? I'm new to this stuff!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the average color?

Comment: have you looked into using GPUImage at all? i dont have any experience with it, but it may be able to help you accomplish what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1):

I've worked for the last 3 months for Metal image processing framework. I think this library may provided a ready-made solution and save you time: https://bitbucket.org/degrader/degradr-core-3.